# Android TestCase for Google Map Marker

Tags: android, google-maps

My app loads list of coordinates and marks them with Map Marker. Wondering if i have to test that using any of the test class, which one that should be. Can you please point me to any link where i can find some information around the testing of these markers. Any help in this regard is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try [Rolectric test framework](http://robolectric.org/).

You can learn how to use Rolectric from [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Robolectric/article.html). You can create [custom shadow objects](http://robolectric.org/custom-shadows/) for your Maps objects, for example markers.